# connection to SQL server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to do connection between SQL server and asp.net (vb code).My SQl Server name is (Local)
 and my vb codes are:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public cn As New SqlConnection
    Public cmd As New SqlCommand
    Public da As SqlDataAdapter
    Public dr As SqlDataReader
    Public ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Public sql As String = Nothing
    Public ConString As String = ("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=dbSQL;Integrated Security=True") 'this is connected to the server


    Public Sub MyCn()
        If cn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then cn.Close()
        cn.ConnectionString = ConString
        cn.Open()
    End Sub
```

but an error message keeps appearing which is :

Cannot open database "dbSQL" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'window8\windows 8'.

please help

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add window8\windows 8 user to the allowed accounts and add the login entry for this user in the desired database. See this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8f1lGdnXJY